# Me and my successor

Tags: word, knowledge, wordplay

> Take a half of me, or my successor,
>    You might become an addict, Good
>    or bad,
>    For many it’s a habit.
>
> Take a half of me, or my successor,
>   You should use it to begone,
>   "Stop annoying me, and leave me alone."
>
> If halves are all you take,
>   Usually, liquid will be the state.

Hint 1:

> We are codenames

Hint 2:

> Computing

Hint 3:

> Half of me can help you stay awake,
>  You may take it while having a break.
>
>  
>  Half of my successor may be labelled,
>  Red, black, green, gold and blue,
>  All walkers, just to name a few.

Hint 4:

> Intel

What am I?
What is my successor?

Comment: First time posting here :)

Comment: looks like some drugs :P or liquor

Comment: @lois6b, apologies. I have modified it to make it a bit clearer. The "Stop annoying me, and leave me alone" is something people say (like a quote I guess)

Comment: Let me know if it is still confusing :)

Comment: Added a hint too

Comment: Added Hint number 2

Comment: So, I got the second part, but the first part is killing me. Could you please give a hint to the first part? I've spent 2 solid days on it with a half confident answer. No pun intended.

Comment: Added Hint number 3

Comment: @MacGyver88 Hopefully that helps with the first part :)

Comment: @El Chapo I'll be on it tomorrow. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Added hint number 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you are

> the Intel architecture codenamed "[Coffee Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_Lake)"

And your successor is

> "[Whiskey Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiskey_Lake_(microarchitecture))"

*Take a half of me, or my successor,
You might become an addict, Good or bad,
For many it’s a habit.*

> People can become addicted to coffee or whiskey.

*Take a half of me, or my successor,
You should use it to begone,
"Stop annoying me, and leave me alone."*

> Could be a reference to the idiom "Go jump in a lake". Found by @tmpearce.

*If halves are all you take,
Usually, liquid will be the state.*

> No matter which half you take (coffee, whiskey, lake) it will be a liquid.

All the hints are satisfied. In particular Hint 3 where

> Coffee can help you stay awake and Johnny *Walker* is a whiskey which comes in the colors mentioned.

Comment: Good find. This has got to be it. Perhaps the "Begone" part has to do with the second part of each phrase (be *gone* and *leave me alone* are both shows/episodes, at least...)

Comment: @tmpearce Perhaps [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Wobegon)?

Comment: @Stiv Yeah, and [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/(go)%20jump%20in%20a/the%20lake#)

Comment: @tmpearce Ah, yes, of course!

Comment: Great work! @tmpearce got it with the [begone part](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/(go)%20jump%20in%20a/the%20lake#)